# Proving that for $1<p< \infty$ $L^p$ spaces are reflexive.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to understand every step of the proof found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Properties_of_Lp_spaces).

It says that we let ${\kappa _{q}} :L^{p}(\mu ) \rightarrow L^{q}(\mu )^{*}$ be the isometry between $L^p$ and it's dual (this is given by the Riesz representation theorem) and then apply the following composition with the transpose (adjoint) of ${\kappa _{q}}$.

$j_{p}:L^{p}(\mu ){\overset {\kappa _{q}}{\longrightarrow }}L^{q}(\mu )^{*}{\overset {\left(\kappa _{p}^{-1}\right)^{*}}{\longrightarrow }}L^{p}(\mu )^{**}$

I am trying to understand why the adjoint is a bijective map. I have constructed it as follows:

$${\left(\kappa _{p}^{-1}\right)^{*}}( F) (\phi) = \phi \circ \kappa _{p}^{-1}(F)$$

where $\phi \in L^{q}(\mu )^{*}$, $F  \in L^{q}(\mu )^{*}$. When $\phi$ is fixed and $F$ varies $\left(\kappa _{p}^{-1}\right)^{*}(F) : L^{q}(\mu )^{*} \rightarrow R$. When $\phi$ varies  we have

$$ {\left(\kappa _{p}^{-1}\right)^{*}} (\phi) = \phi \circ \kappa _{p}^{-1} $$

So $\left(\kappa _{p}^{-1}\right)^{*} : L^{q}(\mu )^{*} \rightarrow L^{q}(\mu )^{**}$.

(Have I understood correctly up to now? also feel free to correct my terminology)

Now If want to show that $\left(\kappa _{p}^{-1}\right)^{*}$ is bijective. I know that  $\kappa _{p}^{-1}$ is by the Riesz Representation theorem so I only need to check $\phi$, but $\phi$ is my input so it will always be bijective and thus I am done.

Have I understood correctly the proof?  I feel like I might be wrong.

Now I am only left to show that this map coincides with the canonical embedding $J$ of $L^p$ into its bidual.

this is because $$ \left( \kappa _{p}^{-1}\right)^{*} \circ \kappa _{p} =  \phi \circ \kappa _{p}^{-1} \circ \kappa _{p} = \phi  $$

and $J(\phi)(f) = \phi(f)$

Where $f \in L^p$, is the canonical embedding.